# How to describe messagepack data structure is used in internal bin protocol? is ASN.1 or BNF suited for it?

Tags: serialization, client-server, notation, asn.1, bnf

My goal is to write specification of simple client-server application protocol for our project where will be few kinds of client: IOS(swift), Android(java) and Web(http/websocket) probably. Server is the python. Our team decided to use MessagePack as a data structure serializer for different requests/responses.

So now i think how to describe such data structures. I don't wanna write the whole description of specification manually and spent time for thinking over different rules and agreements. I would want to point to a notation system description for my colleagues of client development.

My question is a common.
How do you behave with such task? Do you write pure text in your native speaking language or use some notation system? Is it right to use notation system and existing serializer together? I meant ASN.1. It is seemed clear.

Comment: I think you can rule out ASN.1.  MessagePack appears to have its own type system and rules for encoding those types.  It appears ASN.1 and MessagePack are alternatives, not complementary.

Comment: Ok, but how i would better write schema description of messagepack like json-schema for json? Look here https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/issues/202